# AspNet Identity ApplicationDbContext on existing database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

I have an existing database with my application tables and i am about to build a new version for my application using MVC5. I decided to use AspNet Identity framework as part of my application.

The visual studio template i used while creating the project added a file "IdentityModel.cs" and the class

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
  {
    public ApplicationDbContext()
     : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }
  }
```

So i can access the tables Users, Roles and other AspNet Identity tables using the code like:

```
var context = new ApplicationDbContext();
context.Users.ToList();
```

Because of the name Microsoft gave to the class "**Application**DbContext" (and not: **Identity**DbContext for example), i am wondering if that class should be used as "accessor" for all the rest existing tables that not related to AspNet Identity framework or not?

without the so generic name of the class "ApplicationDbContext" i would just use my entity framework project i just added to my solution to access the other tables of my application but i am wondering what is the "best practices". To use the same AspNet Identity ApplicationDbContext accessor (and how?) or to work with two Db accessors, one of the AspNet Identity tables and one for the entity framework i created for the rest of the tables (Db First).

it looks me more logic to use the same dbContext for all the tables, AspNet identity and all the rest of the tables i have in a separate EntityFramework edmx file. How can i use both of them in one dbContext?

Comment: Use a single context. Either add the identity framework tables to your existing context or add your tables to the generated context. It makes no difference. If you don't like the name of the context, rename it. The template just generates a starting point, it isn't canon.

Comment: @CraigW. - Thanks for your comment, i am using entity framework edmx file for the test of the application tables. how can i use the same same db context of the asp.net identity?

Answer (score 0):

AspNet Identity provide something like user manager, it should solve your problem. You don't need to operate on real tables, AspNet Identity should cover table structure and should allow to do high level operations. Your user model should inherit IdentityModel class, then you are able to build your own custom model.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I know that.. i am trying to understand different thing,

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like part of your issue is that while `IdentityFramework` is using [*code-first*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj193542(v=vs.113).aspx) entity framework you are not using code-first for the rest of your application, instead using the older edmx designer approach. I would not try to mix the two into a single context.

Moreover, because `ApplicationDbContext` inherits from `IdentityDbContext` I would leave it alone. The base class implements things like `OnModelCreating` and `ValidateEntity`. If you wanted to use your other context for IdentityFramework you'd need to either have your other context inherit from `IdentityDbContext`--which is bad semantics, because it is not in fact just an identity context--or you'd need to implement these methods manually.

It is easy, however, to point the identity framework context to the same database as your other entity framework items. Just replace `"DefaultConnection"` in your `ApplicationDbContext` with whatever the name of the connection string you use for your other stuff is.